# Unable to install TurboJson 1.3.2 using easy_install

Tags: python, turbogears

`easy_install -U TurboJson` is failing with the below error-

```
user@ubuntu-dev:~$ sudo easy_install -U TurboJSON
Searching for TurboJSON
Reading pypi.python.org/simple/TurboJSON link
Best match: TurboJson 1.3.2
Downloading TurboJson-1.3.2-py2.7.egg#md5=8708fcb8979c661104c9b444e5428484
Processing TurboJson-1.3.2-py2.7.egg
Moving TurboJson-1.3.2-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Adding TurboJson 1.3.2 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TurboJson-1.3.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for TurboJSON
Searching for simplejson>=1.9.1
Reading pypi.python.org/simple/simplejson/ link
Best match: simplejson 3.8.1
Downloading simplejson-3.8.1.tar.gz#md5=b8441f1053edd9dc335ded8c7f98a974
Processing simplejson-3.8.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-4VcmRi/simplejson-3.8.1/setup.cfg
Running simplejson-3.8.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-4VcmRi/simplejson-3.8.1/egg-dist-tmp-K89rCq
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
simplejson.tests.init: module references file Adding simplejson 3.8.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson-3.8.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Searching for PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2600
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/PEAK-Rules/
No local packages or download links found for PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2600

error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2600')

user@ubuntu-dev:~$
```

https://pypi.python.org/simple/peak-rules/ seems to be broken. It does not list any packages which is very strange. Earlier, it was mostly providing PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2713.

Comment: `easy_install http://www.turbogears.org/2.1/downloads/current/PEAK-Rules-0.5a1.dev-r2686.tar.gz` to get PEAK-Rules, then re-run `easy_install TurboJSON`.

Comment: I think the pypi peak-rules package is broken as you suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, the PyPi page for PEAK-Rules does not have any packages available for installation, as you suspected in your question.

The solution is to install the PEAK-Rules dependency yourself, then install TurboJSON afterwards.

First, run:
`easy_install http://www.turbogears.org/2.1/downloads/current/PEAK-Rules-0.5a1.dev-r2686.tar.gz`

This should install `PEAK-Rules 0.5a1.dev-r2686` successfully, which will satisfy the TurboJSON requirement of `PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2600`.

Now, if you run `(sudo) easy_install -U TurboJSON`, the installation should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks! I used the same approach as a workaround right now.
TurboGears 2.0.4 also provides PEAK-Rules 0.5a1.dev-r2686. So, I ran:
easy_install http://www.turbogears.org/2.0/downloads/current/PEAK-Rules-0.5a1.dev-r2686.tar.gz 

Do you have any clue whether PyPi page for PEAK-Rules is temporarily broken or was it always like this? I feel it has been accidentally broken because earlier while installing TurboJson 1.3.2,  PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2713 was getting installed as a dependency.